# Submit form on change of dropdown only when special value is selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select

I have a dropdown list with a few options (e.g. 7). The form should be submitted when one of the last 3 options is selected. On the first 4 options the form should not be submitted.

`onChange="this.form.submit()"` does not help - the form will be submitted on every change...

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance

Hias

Comment: You need a function to be called in onChange that looks for the value you've selected.

Answer (score 0):

Do...

`onchange="checkVal();"`

Then in your JS make the function...

```
function checkVal{
    var e = document.getElementById("FORMID");
    var selectedVal = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedVal == val4 || selectedVal == val5 || selectedVal == val6){
         e.submit();
    }
}
```

This will work if you have your options set up with values `<option val="4">number 4</option>` If not you have to use `.text` instead of `.value` to get the `selectedVal` and then compare the text inside the options

Answer (score 0):

It's simple check the value of select element if it's what you want then tell form to submit itself.

**Demo of this**: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6FUM/

```
var f = document.forms['mf'], s= document.getElementById('ss');

s.onchange = function() {
    if (s.value==3) f.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. It works with this code:

```
function checkVal() {
  var f = document.getElementById("FORM-ID");
  var e = document.getElementById("SELECT-ID");
  var selectedVal = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if (selectedVal > 4) {
    f.submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: so if something has value 6 or 5 this will submit.